# Why Asp.Net Core QueryHelpers don't encode @ (at) symbol?

Tags: url, asp.net-core, encoding, query-string

Reading various resources on the internet, it seems, that we have to encode `@` sign in the query params of the URL (as well as in most of the other places of the URL).

I was trying to generate an URL in my ASP.NET Core app and found a way to do this using `QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(...)`. But it seems not to be encoding `@` symbol, even though it is encoding all other symbols that I tested.

**Question:** Is there some particular reason for such behaviour, or is it just a bug?

My test that passes:

```
var url0 = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("base", "field", "&?=čž/");
Assert.Equal("base?field=%26%3F%3D%C4%8D%C5%BE%2F", url0);

var url = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("base", "field", "@");
Assert.Equal("base?field=@", url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because, simply, `@` doesn't *need* to be encoded. It's not a character that means anything in the context of a URL, so it's fine as is. The characters like `&`, `?` and `=` all have meaning in the context of a URL and thus must be encoded. As far as the unicode characters go, I believe these are encoded just for safety. Unicode is technically supported in URLs, but support for that is relatively recent, and may not be universally implemented. It's not going *hurt* to encode them, and that way it'll just work without issue.

Comment: I would add that `@` actually is one of the reserved characters (in the RFC) and is used for authentication in URLs. Therefore it is kinda weird to simply allow it in the URL at all.

Comment: And there seems to be another case when you need encoding, even if the character doesn't hurt a URL. E.g. `+` has to be encoded, as otherwise, browser will interpret it as a ` ` , because `decodeURIComponent('+')=' '`